# Using "while read" and "for i in" resulting in ambiguous redirect

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, while-loop

```
# while read a b ; do echo $a $b ; done < `for i in \`cat users.txt\` ; do PHPVER=\`selectorctl --user-current --user=$i\` ; echo $i $PHPVER ; done | awk '{print $1, $2}' | sed 's/native/5.3/g'`

-bash: `for i in \`cat users.txt\` ; do PHPVER=\`selectorctl --user-current --user=$i\` ; echo $i $PHPVER ; done | awk '{print $1, $2}' | sed 's/native/5.3/g'`: ambiguous redirect
```

If you remove the while read statement, the output of:

```
# for i in `cat users.txt` ; do PHPVER=`selectorctl --user-current --user=$i` ; echo $i $PHPVER ; done | awk '{print $1, $2}' | sed 's/native/5.3/g'

user1 5.4
user2 5.4
user3 5.3
```

So I need to take these 2 columns and turn each into a variable this way I can then run them in a command like so:

```
# selectorctl --set-user-current=$b --user=$a
```

however when  I add the while read statement, it throws the ambiguous redirect

Comment: First of all, use `$( . . . )` instead of backquotes(`\` . . . \``). It makes nesting much easier - no need to use something like `\\``

Comment: & Your `< $(for ...)` should be changed to `< <(for ...)`

Comment: Have a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: If the `#` prompt means you're running as root, then it's a bad idea to do that.  It's doubly a bad idea to experiment as root; you can do damage when you don't intend to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really unclear what you're trying to do. You might want to do something like

```
while read -r user; do
    read phpver rest < <(selectorctl --user-current --user="$user")
    output="$user $phpver"
    echo "${output//native/5.3}"
done < users.txt
```

[Don't use `for` to read lines from a file](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: Pretty sad that I've been using for to read files forever, just a habit that I never new was incorrect.

How does
    echo "${output//native/5.3}"
replace native with 5.3, I thought you always had to use something like sed to replace. I tried googling // but is it the echo that can do the replace or? Super confused on that

Also, the output from 
    selectorctl --user-current --user="$user"
gives more than just 2 words, example:
    user 5.5    5.5.34  /opt/alt/php55/usr/bin/php-cgi
which is why I used awk. Can I 'awk' the first 2 words $1 $2 within that echo statement?

Comment: @JCats : Read the ~3rd section in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters (Parameter substitutions) for info on `${var//targ/repl}` . To be fair, it's rather obscure, but very powerful feature of the shell. Good luck.

Comment: @JCats, would have been good to include that detail in your question. Updated. That's a process substitution: you can read about it in the bash manual.

Comment: @glenn jackman Do you mind me asking how the changes you made got it to only output the first 2 words.  I understand $user but how does $phpver only show the first word when: **selectorctl --user-current --user="$user"** gives you 3

Comment: The `read` command splits the text and assigns words to the given variable names. I gave 2 varnames to read: the first word goes into `phpver` and all the other words go into `rest`

Comment: @glennjackman Oh clever ok got it, I didn't know rest was a variable, thanks so much for the explanation and your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r user; do
    phpver=$(selectorctl --user-current --user="$user")
    output="$user $phpver"
    echo "${output//native/5.3}" | awk '{print $1, $2}'
done < users.txt
```

Is the placement of *awk* ok here or would there be a more proper way of removing the extra lines from the output which in this case is:

```
user 5.4    5.4.45  /opt/alt/php54/usr/bin/php-cgi
```

but I need

```
user 5.4
```

Comment: ...and you've got a bunch of quoting bugs that http://shellcheck.net/ would catch.

Comment: I corrected the quotes, as far as the for statement, Ill have to mess around with it a bit.

Comment: (...also, piping awk to anything else is generally unnecessary -- awk can do everything `sed` can, and [from a text-processing perspective] anything bash can do as well itself).